# Overriding core layout XML located in "base" not in "frontend"

Tags: magento2, layout, magento2.2, overrides

I want to remove `tier_price` from `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/base/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
<referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="configurable" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="tier_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Render\TierPriceBox</item>
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_ConfigurableProduct::product/price/tier_price.phtml</item>
                </item>
                <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox</item>
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_ConfigurableProduct::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Since the `<remove>` layout instruction doesn't work on elements other than blocks or containers, I have no choice but to **override the whole layout file in my theme**.

[Documentation says](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html#fedg_layout_override_default):

> **Override base layouts**
>
> To add an overriding base layout file (to override a base layout provided by the module):
>
> Put a layout file with the same name in the following location:
>
> <theme_dir>/Namespace_Module/layout/override/base/<layout1>.xml
>
> This file override the following layouts:
>
> /view/frontend/layout/<layout1>.xml

The above assumes the layout file to override is in the `frontend` folder. Mine is not. **Where do I put my override layout?** I could not find anything in the documentation.

I tried `app/design/frontend/<theme_name>/default/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/layout/override/base/catalog_product_prices.xml` that returns an error of course, as it tries to find the original in `frontend`:

```
Exception #0 (LogicException): Overriding view file '/var/www/vhosts/sitename/local/app/design/frontend//default/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/layout/override/base/catalog_product_prices.xml' does not match to any of the files.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Create file in your theme as below :

**app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[theme]/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml.**

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't work — copied the core file to the path you suggested, removed the <code>tier_price</code> item, flushed all caches, but the tier price is still present on the configurable product details page.

That path works for layout files in "frontend" only, mine is in "base", hence the question.

Comment: base folder it's default fallback for all arias and used to share resources across of areas..you can override this using the above path..